# Spring boot, GORM, and unit tests

Tags: grails, gradle, spring-boot, grails-orm, spock

I have a project built using Spring Boot. In this project I have included the [gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/tree/master/boot-plugins/gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot) plugin in order to use Grails' GORM object mapping sugar. When running the project, GORM does its thing without issue and everything is great. Tests, on the other hand, are another matter. In a Grails project I would need to annotate my test cases with `@Mock([DomainOne, DomainTwo])`. The GORM plugin for spring boot works differently.

An answer for another question around Spring Boot and GORM linked to [HibernateMixin](https://github.com/grails/grails-datastore-test-support/blob/master/src/test/groovy/grails/test/mixin/hibernate/HibernateMixinSpec.groovy) from the `grails-datastore-test-support` plugin. In order to use this mixin, a project must also have the grails `@TestMixin` annotation which is included in an artifact that pulls in the rest of Grails. This same answer also suggested use of [HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4/src/test/groovy/grails/orm/bootstrap/HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializerSpec.groovy) in order to initialize GORM in a spec's `setup()` method. Unfortunately I could not get this to work despite seeming to be the best bet.

Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript { // Defines dependencies and repos for the build script itself
  repositories { mavenCentral() }
  dependencies { classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE") }
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

version = 1.0
mainClassName='foo.bar.Baz'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone' }
  maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshots' }
  flatDir { dirs 'lib' }
}

dependencies {
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc") {
      exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
  }
  compile("org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker") // ActiveMQ
  compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.4') // Commons IO
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j") // log 4j
  compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all')
  compile('org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc41') // JDBC
  compile('log4j:log4j:1.2.17') // Default logging provider
  compile("org.grails:gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot:5.0.0.RC2") // I summon thee, gorm
  testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0")
  testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
  testCompile('com.h2database:h2:1.3.148') // h2 for GORM use during tests
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Here's my test case:

```
class DataTypeValidatorSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
        // Fails with "org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread"
        def datastoreInitializer = new HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer(MyDomainClass)
        def applicationContext = new GenericApplicationContext()
        def dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(
            "jdbc:h2:mem:grailsDb1;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1",
            'sa', ''
        )
        dataSource.driverClassName = Driver.name
        applicationContext.beanFactory.registerSingleton("dataSource", dataSource)
        datastoreInitializer.configureForBeanDefinitionRegistry(applicationContext)
        applicationContext.refresh() // is this needed?
    }

    void "should do gorm stuff"() {
        given:
            MyDomainClass instance = new MyDomainClass(name: 'foo').save()
        when:
            MyDomainClass locatedInstance = MyDomainClass.findByName('foo')
        then:
            instance == locatedInstance
    }

}
```

I run the tests with `gradle test`. The code in the setup method for my spec is a pretty direct translation of the setup used in the HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializerSpec linked above.

Note, this is *not* a Grails project and if possible I'd like to keep the Grails related code to a minimum. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if it isn't grails project, so, please remove tag grails

Comment: I've included the Grails tag as it relies on GORM and will likely need some similar handling. I think someone with Grails expertise would be in the best position to help with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to get mocking to work without dragging in Grails core. I just removed GORM and went with Spring JPA / Hibernate based entities and repositories. These are easy to use with Spock and provide a more visible code flow for persisting, updating, etc. Sorry GORM.

Answer (score -1):

This is a Spring Boot application so use the Boot integration testing annotations:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

If you use these GORM will be loaded using the mechanism provided by `gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot`

Comment: Graeme, I wasn't able to get things working with the `@IntegrationTest` annotation. Should this be used in combination with the hibernate configuration annotation mentioned above? Could you provide a little more detail?

Comment: I'm seeing same issue as OP with or without @SpringBootTest annotation